# How can I load a module with RequireJS for testing in a testing framework like Jasmine?

Tags: testing, requirejs, jasmine

I am new to JavaScript and try to test functions defined in a RequireJS Module.
That means i have some code like this:

```
define([...], function(...){
    var ModuleName = Base.extend({
        init: function(){
            //some code
        };
    });
}
```

Now I want to test the function init().
I load the object from my spec.js, this works:

```
describe("ModuleName", function(){
    var mod = require(['../js/app/ModuleName.js'], function(ModuleName) {});

    it("exists", function(){
        expect(mod).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

This passes well.
But when I add this code, it fails:

```
it("contains init", function(){
    expect(mod.init).toBeDefined();
});
```

I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using RequireJS properly.

The following solution needs the use of `beforeAll`, which can be added to Jasmine with [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-before-all). Your code could be something like this:

```
describe("ModuleName", function() {
    var mod;

    beforeAll(function (done) {
        // This loads your module and saves it in `mod`.
        require(['../js/app/ModuleName'], function(mod_) {
            mod = _mod;
            done();
        });
    });

    it("exists", function(){
        expect(mod).toBeDefined();
        expect(mod.init).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

As I recall, the *return value* of `require` called with an array of dependencies is a reference to `require` itself. So yes, it is defined but, no, it is not the value of the module you were trying to load. To get a module value, you have to do something like I did in the code above.

If your tests happen to be in a RequireJS module, you could also just add the module to be tested to the list of dependencies:

```
define([..., '../js/app/ModuleName'], function (..., mod) {
    describe("ModuleName", function() {
        it("exists", function(){
            expect(mod).toBeDefined();
            expect(mod.init).toBeDefined();
        });
    });
});
```

I've used both methods above in different circumstances.

Side note: I've removed the `.js` from the module name in the code above. You generally do not want to put the `.js` extension to module names you give to RequireJS.

Comment: This doesn't work for me because, for some reason, the it block is called after the beforeAll...

Comment: OK, I was able to make it work, the issue was that I didn't call `done.` Can anyone explain what `done` does and why it's necessary?

Comment: The `require` call is asynchronous so you have to tell Jasmine when it is done. You do this by calling `done`.