# What does calling 'done' do in the context of asynchronous testing?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, requirejs, jasmine

In [Louis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29648753), there is the following code:

> ```
> describe("ModuleName", function() {
>     var mod;
>
>     beforeAll(function (done) {
>         // This loads your module and saves it in `mod`.
>         require(['../js/app/ModuleName'], function(mod_) {
>             mod = _mod;
>             done();
>         });
>     });
>
>     it("exists", function(){
>         expect(mod).toBeDefined();
>         expect(mod.init).toBeDefined();
>     });
> });
> ```

They pass a function `done()` into the mix. Why do they use this?

Comment: See http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support

Comment: When you copy code from questions or answers on SO you have to provide attribution, and properly quote what you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So that when you do something async, like call `require()`, you can signal when it's complete. Otherwise the test framework would have no way to know when you're done doing async stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `done()` is so you can indicate to the testing framework when an asynchronous operation has completed.